# How can a user cancel their Amazon FPS recurring token?

Tags: recurring-billing, amazon-fps

The Amazon FPS documentation says in several places that a customer can cancel their recurring payment token at any time from Amazon's UI, and that Amazon will then notify the application that the token has been cancelled. I'd like to test this.

How does a user do that?

As a test user, I see nothing in my Amazon Payments UI that shows my existing recurring payment tokens so I can cancel them. Googling for an answer gives me lots of results explaining how my application can cancel the token, but none explaining how the user can cancel their own token behind my app's back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should see any tokens that your account has authorized in `Your Account > Edit My Account Settings > Manage my payment authorizations`.

From there you should be able to cancel your reoccurring token.